What are the necessary requirements needed to use termux-x11 in a proot environment?
I have successfully gotten my proot environment setup. I would like to enable termux-x11 for it instead of VNC.
I know that proot-distro exists, and like it. I am mainly doing this for learning and trying to debug a weird performance issue in proot-distro.
I am able to execute termux-x11 inside the proot environment. However, it just does nothing, no error returned, no feedback whatsoever. I am simply back to the prompt.
I am currently investigating proot-distro install and login parameters. I have narrowed it down to an install issue. Proot-distro must have some additional setup for termux-x11.
I will continue my searches, but if anyone knows more and can provide their expertise I will greatly appreciate it!
